# How do I make a button in the UI run my function?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I want to create a button in Blender to select a file for use elsewhere in my program. The command for selecting the file is:

```
bpy.ops.an.invoke_function_1(callback="#('executeSocketCallback', ((('NodeTree', 'Text File Reader.001'), False, 'path'), '_selector_PATH'))", confirm=False, passEvent=False, data="setPath", invokeWithData=True)
```

This is what I have so far:

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Panel

class SimpleToolPanel(Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_label = 'Tools Tab Label'
    bl_context = 'objectmode'
    bl_category = 'Coordinate Paths'

def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.operator("What do I put HERE?", text='Select file for path 1')

def register():
bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleToolPanel)

def unregister():
bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleToolPanel)

if __name__ == '__main__':
register()
```

I am not a Python expert or a Blender expert so this is probably a dumb question, but how do make the button execute the command?

Comment: Try `layout.operator("an.invoke_function_1").callback = blah`

Comment: for "blah" what do I put? (srry, I'm a noob)